# How to create a Task List based on Document Library Expiration Date?

Tags: tasks, timeline

SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Version | Task List / Time Line

I have a contract library with 100s of contracts and their expiration dates. 
I want to create a separate Time Line (task) for display to show when each contract is expiring.

Is it possible to do that without having to manually create a Tasks List and doing hours of data entries?

I have ZERO coding experience. So, would prefer to stay away from coding. If coding is the only solution, I would appreciate steps on how to also implement the codes.

Comment: Take this for what it is worth, I have never tried what you are looking to do.   Create the Task List.  Then create a column for the task list and use the lookup type.  Choose your library and then select the information you want (expiration date, title, etc.).    It will pull all information you select into the list.  I have done something similar, but not into a Task List.  I am not sure how it will look in a task list.

Comment: @DavidJenkins Wouldn't you have to manually create a new task for each contract?

Comment: Do you need the task to be linked back to the contract, or is it enough that the task has the contract title and/or ID?  Should the task date change when the contract expiration changes? Who does the task get assigned to? Would you be entering that automatically? Or are you just wanting something that looks like a timeline?

Comment: @ErinL Yes.  We have a process were we pull in some information from one list to a follow-on list.  There is a manual process, but not re-creating/entering the data as it pulls it in.  I am less sure of how it will react with the Task List.

Comment: @ErinL - thank you first for your thoughts.
I would prefer to Link the task data to the document library to reduce error, of course. Yes on linking to Cotract title and expiration date. Yes the task date should change if the expiration date changes. Yes this should be automatic. Of course, if not possible easily, than at least manually for now.

Comment: @DavidJenkins - thanks for your thoughts; I will try your approach to see if it works. As long as the automatic data being extracted is date/time, and title of the file, I think it should have normal timeline behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description , to avoid manually creating Task list I suggest to create a custom view called time line or Tasks as you need and show only the fields available to your list like  contract name , contract period , contract expiration date , then try to create a filter with expiration date to show all contract that not expired.

you can also add calculated field to subtract expiration date from current date, you can find how to create calculated list filed [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-data-in-lists-or-libraries-C5261743-667F-4833-BEDE-E516CEF2A0E1).

For more enhancement you can build conditional formatting on the calculated field to show it as color as mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904774/how-do-i-apply-colors-to-a-sharepoint-list-based-on-status)

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I will try your approach. This is new to me. So, I am excited to learn new approaches.

Comment: This was my first thought too. But it wouldn't provide the functionality of assigning a task to a person with an action to indicate the task is complete. If you don't need to send a task to someone, then this is definitely the best option. If you need the functionality of a task list, let us know.